# Gap below question count when loading questions page

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design

When I load the [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), there is a large gap below the question count and above my favorite tags:

[image: Screenshot]

After the page finishes loading, the gap disappears and the favorite tags jump up to just below the question count.

I don't have any local adblockers or anything running, but I am behind a WebSense filter.  I can't seem to replicate this behavior on superuser or here on meta.  Browser info: Firefox 7.0.1 with add-ons enabled: Firebug 1.8.3, FireGestures 1.6.6, HTTPS-Everywhere 1.0.3, Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant 0.0.0

Comment: Sure you don't have adblockers? I see ads there.

Comment: Not 100% sure, as anything WebSense blocks might not go through, but usually things blocked by WebSense show up as an awful blue and orange box notifying me that the content's been blocked.  It seems more like the ad isn't loading correctly so the div collapses itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only run ads on Stack Overflow and Server Fault (that are likely blocked by your firewall/filter).  The rest are internal and less-likely to trip those triggers.

Unfortunately this is a problem on your side, and not something we can resolve.  To get the ads that should be displayed there, contact the administrator of your WebSense filter.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up.  I'm sad that the ads are blocked, but have no business reason to request that the WebSense filter be modified.  I'll just have to keep visiting from my home computer to ensure that the ads get the pageviews they deserve. :-)